# Return MAX from Column A with MATCH against Column B in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been scratching my head on this one for a few hours now.

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns. Column A contains the Date Period formatted as such 200401 for the first month of 2004. Column B contains a Reference Number.

In Column C I would like to have a formula that returns the highest value in Column A using the reference number from Column B. As shown below

```
COL A     COL B     COL C
200407    DIFA0694  200408
200408    DIFA0694  200408
200311    DIFA0704  200801
200403    DIFA0704  200801
200801    DIFA0704  200801
200311    DIFA0712  ......
200311    DIFA0712  ......
200409    DIFA0712  ......
200411    DIFA0712  ...... 
200312    DIFA0736  ......
200312    DIFA0736  ......
200512    DIFA0736  ......
200404    DIFA0763  ......
200405    DIFA0763  ......
200405    DIFA0763  ......
200807    DIFA0763  ......
200405    DIFA0780  ......
200408    DIFA0780  ......
200312    DIFA0780  ......
200401    DIFA0780  ......
```

So, the COL C value should be the most recent period for the job reference shown in COL B.

I have tried this using a combination of MAX, INDEX and MATCH but to no avail. I believe this is because the INDEX, MATCH does not return an array of values.

I would appreciate any guidance that anybody could offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
on c2 paste:

```
=MAX(IF(b:b=b2,a:a,""))
```

and drag it down. 
dont forget to press ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: You need to specify that your two columns start at row 1 (with a $ absolute reference), and end at the row above the current row (with a relative reference). Like so: =MAX(IF(B$1:B1=B2,C$1:C,"")) Although I would say something other than an array formula is likely preferable. Note also that it is unwise to use an Array formula over the entire length of a column, circular reference or no [Array formulas are more intensive, basically, so calculate too slow on such a large area].